# Feed an RTSP stream to Wowza Streaming Engine

Tags: rtsp, live-streaming, wowza, rtsp-client

I'm getting an RTSP live video stream from an IP camera. My URL looks like this rtsp://xxx:80/img/vid.sav I want to open this stream on Wowza. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a stream file and then ingest the stream into Wowza.  Essentially create a file called camera.stream and in it, put your rtsp url. Then within the wowza engine manager (found at http://[your-ip]:8088/) and go to the application you've created for this test and then click on your stream files.  Thereafter there will be an option to connect.

You can refer to their stream file guide found [here](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?584-How-to-create-and-use-stream-files-in-Wowza-Streaming-Engine-Manager).

Comment: Hey Matt! Thanks for your response. And I have already done that, but the status says "waiting for the stream" even after hours.

Comment: You might want to look at the logs/wowzastreamingengine_access.log file to see if its having trouble finding the source.  Also ensure that you test your rtsp url out in VLC first to ensure what you are attempting to ingest will resolve.